# How to set response time out to get data from Odoo?

Tags: c#, odoo, odoo-11

I got product from Odoo by API code, its working fine for 1000 products.

but, suffering error like 'The operation has timed out.' while try to getting 2000 products from odoo by API

Is this any parameter need to set timeout while web response got from Odoo ?

have a look for code snippets,

```
[XmlRpcMethod("execute")]
object[] read(string dbName, int userId, string dbPwd, string model, string method, int[] ids);
object[] laProducts = loRpcRecord.read(lsOdooDBName, liUserid, lsOdooDBPassword, OdooHelper.Models.Product, OdooHelper.Methods.Read, laCombineProductIds);
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated !

Comment: This works on the backend of odoo, system parameters holds this functionality.

Comment: Which API endpoint are you using, using `xmlrpc` protocol or any other means, update the question in details.

Comment: @arryph: yes, please have a look my updated Que.

Comment: Do you use workers resp. multi threaded mode?

Comment: @CZoellner: No, didn't use

Comment: Are you sure, because that's unusual. Can you please share the Log entry with your error message and some surounding log entries as addtional info.